# How to exclude different levels of subdirectories with cp?

Tags: find, cp, directory-structure

This is a follow-up question to my original post: [find & cp command doesn't copy 1st level directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/762085/108618)

I have a directory structure like this:

```
test folders
├── 1
│   ├── 1-1
│   ├── 1-2
│   └── 1-3
├── 2
│   ├── 2-1
│   ├── 2-2
│   └── 2-3
├── 3
│   ├── 3-1
│   ├── 3-2
│   └── 3-3
└── 4
    ├── 4-1
    ├── 4-2
    └── 4-3

16 directories, 0 files
```

and I am struggling with copying ONLY the 1st level folders -- 1,2,3,4 excluding all subfolders using `find` & `cp` commands

```
├── 1
├── 2
├── 3
└── 4
```

Working directory is `/home/username/Downloads/test folders`.

My failed attempt is in the linked question. There we've established the fact that `cp` doesn't see `find`'s commands with `-maxdepth`.

Is there another command with `find` and `cp` that allows `-maxdepth` to make it easier to copy files? Is there even a `-maxdepth` equivalent for `cp`, if `find`'s commands can't be linked with `cp`?

[edit]: In addition, I want to only copy the 1st level directories, such as 1, 2, 3 and 4. I do not want to copy files. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Does it **have** to be `cp`? `rsync` usually handles those kind of sophisticated copy requirements much better. See [rsync recursively with a certain depth of subfolders](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178362/rsync-recursively-with-a-certain-depth-of-subfolders) for example.

Comment: By the way, I assume you want to copy the 1st level directories **including the files in them**, just without the subfolders, is that right?

Comment: yes that's right, exclude files from all levels but exclude subfolders in the 1, 2,3,4

Comment: Anmac1789 your response ^^ reads to me as "yes" agreeing to the first level directories being copied _with their files_, but then you say "_exclude files from all levels_". Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/762088/edit) to state whether copying should include first level directories and their immediate files, or copying should include the first level directories only, without any files

Comment: Tar can also do what you want.

Comment: Looks like you are using GNU tools. If you don't mind the warning messages because your didn't mention the `-r` option, why not use `cp --parents */* destination_directory`?

Comment: @xhienne Does --parents only copy the level that you define ?

Comment: @anmac1789 No, `cp --parents */* dest` will copy the files among your parameters `*/*` (if you want to copy more levels, then change the parameter: `*/*/*`, `*/*/*/*`, etc). The `--parents` option will just recreate the directory hierarchy for those files in the destination directory. Just try it out!

Comment: This works as intended by copying folders which are 3 levels deep but it copies all 3 levels. How do I copy, just the 3rd level ?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to copy the directories and no files or sub-directories, it' easy:

```
terdon@oregano test folders $ tree
.
├── 1
│   ├── 1-1
│   ├── 1-2
│   ├── 1-3
│   ├── file-1
│   └── file-2
├── 2
│   ├── 2-1
│   ├── 2-2
│   ├── 2-3
│   ├── file-1
│   └── file-2
├── 3
│   ├── 3-1
│   ├── 3-2
│   ├── 3-3
│   ├── file-1
│   └── file-2
└── 4
    ├── 4-1
    ├── 4-2
    ├── 4-3
    ├── file-1
    └── file-2

17 directories, 8 files
```

Using the above example, you can re-create the top level directories with:

```
terdon@oregano test folders $ find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec mkdir ../results/{} \;
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘../results/.’: File exists
$ tree ../results/
../results/
├── 1
├── 2
├── 3
└── 4

5 directories, 0 files
```

You can safely ignore the error message. That is just because it also finds `.`, the current directory, and tries to create `../results/.`, that current directory, which already exists.

If you also want to copy the top-level files, you can do it in two steps:

```
terdon@oregano test folders $ find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec mkdir ../results/{} \;
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘../results/.’: File exists
$ find . -maxdepth 2 -type f -exec cp {} ../results/{} \;
```

Which produces:

```
$ tree ../results/
../results/
├── 1
│   ├── file-1
│   └── file-2
├── 2
│   ├── file-1
│   └── file-2
├── 3
│   ├── file-1
│   └── file-2
└── 4
    ├── file-1
    └── file-2
```

You can also do it in a single pass with:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec sh -c 'mkdir ../results/$1 && cp {}/* ../results/$1' sh {} \;
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘../results/.’: File exists
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory './3/3-1'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory './3/3-2'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory './3/3-3'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory './1/1-1'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory './1/1-2'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory './1/1-3'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory './4/4-1'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory './4/4-2'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory './4/4-3'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory './2/2-1'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory './2/2-2'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory './2/2-3'
```

Since we are using `cp` without `-r`, only files will be copied. You'll get those warnings, but again, you can safely ignore them. You can also silence them by redirecting to `/dev/null`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec sh -c 'mkdir ../results/$1 && cp {}/* ../results/$1' sh {} \; 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: so does it mean that cp without -r only copies files in the current directory and with -r it's suppose to copy subdirectories as well but cp..doesn't have a switch for copying subdirectories at a certain depth level ?

Comment: @anmac1789 `-r` doesn't differentiate between files and directories. Remember, on *nix systems like Linux, [_everything is a file_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file). So `cp` alone, without `-r` can only copy files, but if you give it `-r` it means "copy everything, including directories". So yes, it has no understanding of depth, it's either just a file, or everything.

Comment: ok gotcha makes sense so there is no really other option for cp that excludes depth except using mkdir with {} ?

Comment: @anmac1789 no other option for `cp` no. It really doesn't have many options, see `man cp`.

Comment: can cp "filter" out files and leave only directories kind of like type d that find command does ?

Comment: @anmac1789 no, it doesn't. Didn't you read `man cp` as I suggested?

Comment: ok, ur right cp doesn't have many flexible commands